# How to get all item in customadapter listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have custom `Adapter` for `ListView` which contains different `Layout` for each item in the `ListView`. The selection of `Layout` depends on `getitemType` am choosing `Layout` file.but first three items occupying my screen when I scroll that items are repeating till my list size but position value gets changed.

```
     View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
      case TYPE_MENUUPLOAD:
      case TYPE_UPLOADIMAGE: 
      ViewHolder holder4 = null;
      if (convertView == null) 
       {
            holder4 = new ViewHolder();
            convertView=Inflater.inflate(R.layout.uploadphoto,null);
            convertView.setTag(holder4);
        } else 
        { 
            holder4 = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }       
      return convertView;

      case TYPE_USER:
          ViewHolder holder5 = null;     
          if (convertView == null) 
          { 
              holder5 = new ViewHolder();
              convertView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.user, null);
              convertView.setTag(holder5); 
           } else 
           {
               holder5 = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
          return convertView; 

      case TYPE_UPLOADVIDEO:            
          ViewHolder holder6 = null;
          if (convertView == null) 
          {
              holder6 = new ViewHolder();
              convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.uploadvideo, null);
              convertView.setTag(holder6);   
           } 
          else 
          {
              holder6 = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }return convertView;

    };
```

Comment: Can you show us your getView?

Comment: Very difficult to read the code. Can't it be formatted for readibility?

Comment: @Balajee accept the edit suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public int getViewTypeCount() {
   return 3; //in your case.
}

public int getItemViewType (int position) {
   case TYPE_MENUUPLOAD:
   case TYPE_UPLOADIMAGE:
      return 0;
   case TYPE_USER:
      return 1;
   case TYPE_UPLOADVIDEO:
      return 2;
}
```

Your existing getView method should work without any change.

Comment: hi i m doing in this way only..do you have any idea about facebook newsfeed implementation

Comment: Yes And I have implemented a similar feed in my proj.

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem I believe your edit is factorized version of Balajee's original code.

Comment: can i see ur feed implementation

Answer (score 0):

In you your case you need to remove the `if (convertView == null)` checks. As it is causing the problems.

for `case TYPE_MENUUPLOAD:
      case TYPE_UPLOADIMAGE:` your inflate the View...So when `case TYPE_USER:` comes you have a null check on the `convertView` which is not `null` as It is init in other `case`, so you have wrong View.

just use your code code as

```
  View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
  case TYPE_MENUUPLOAD:
  case TYPE_UPLOADIMAGE: 
  return Inflater.inflate(R.layout.uploadphoto,null);;
  case TYPE_USER:
  return Inflater.inflate(R.layout.user, null);; 
  case TYPE_UPLOADVIDEO:
  return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.uploadvideo, null);;
  }
```

`View Holder` pattern will not be use full in your case.

**EDIT:**
I think of another solutions as Suggested by Prakash. But his solution will do the trick in this fashion, If it do..

```
View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
 ViewHolder holder = null;
 if (convertView == null) {
  case TYPE_MENUUPLOAD:
  case TYPE_UPLOADIMAGE:
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView=Inflater.inflate(R.layout.uploadphoto,null);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    break;
case TYPE_USER:
       holder = new ViewHolder();  
       convertView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.user, null);
       convertView.setTag(holder); 
    break;
  case TYPE_UPLOADVIDEO:            
       holder = new ViewHolder();  
       convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.uploadvideo, null);
       convertView.setTag(holder); 
    break;    
 } 
 else 
 {
    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
 }return convertView;

};
```

Comment: this is not correct, creating views every time is very heavy on the GC.

Comment: so  in that which way i can use for make it efficient

Comment: Have you implemented getItemViewType and getViewTypeCount methods?

Comment: @PrakashNadar you are right it is not a good way to this...but in case of Balajee's problem, I do not think of any efficient solution..

Comment: @Naeem, there is a better way of doing it. The above solution will cause GC to kick in more frequently and cause UI freezes.

Comment: am getting item now properly..scrolling is happening slowly in which i can make it fast